# How to build a good training data set for machine learning and predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, j48

I have a school project to make a program that uses the Weka tools to make predictions on football (soccer) games.

Since the algorithms are already there (the J48 algorithm), I need just the data. I found a website that offers football game data for free and I tried it in Weka but the predictions were pretty bad so I assume my data is not structured properly.

I need to extract the data from my source and format it another way in order to make new attributes and classes for my model. Does anyone know of a course/tutorial/guide on how to properly create your attributes and classes for machine learning predictions? Is there a standard that describes the best way of choosing the attributes of a data set for training a machine learning algorithm? What's the approach on this?

here's an example of the data that I have at the moment: http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1516/E0.csv

and here is what the columns mean: http://www.football-data.co.uk/notes.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be that the data set you have is too small. Suppose you have ten variables and each variable has a range of 10 values. There are 10^10 possible configurations of these variables. It is unlikely your data set will  be this large let alone cover all of the possible configurations. The trick is to narrow down the variables to the most relevant to avoid this large potential search space.

A second problem is that certain combinations of variables may be more significant than others.

The J48 algorithm attempts to to find the most relevant variable using entropy at each level in the tree. each path through the tree can be thought of as an AND condition: V1==a & V2==b ...

This covers the significance due to joint interactions. But what if the outcome is a result of A&B&C OR W&X&Y? The J48 algorithm will find only one and it will be the one where the the first variable selected will have the most overall significance when considered alone.

So, to answer your question, you need to not only find a training set which will cover the most common variable configurations in the "general" population but find an algorithm which will faithfully represent these training cases. Faithful meaning it will generally apply to unseen cases.

It's not an easy task. Many people and much money are involved in sports betting. If it were as easy as selecting the proper training set, you can be sure it would have been found by now.

EDIT:

It was asked in the comments how to you find the proper algorithm. The answer is the same way you find a needle in a haystack. There is no set rule. You may be lucky and stumble across it but in a large search space you won't ever know if you have. This is the same problem as finding the optimum point in a very convoluted search space.

A short-term answer is to

- **Think about what the algorithm can really accomplish.** The J48 (and similar) algorithms are best suited for classification where the  influence of the variables on the result are well known and follow a hierarchy. Flower classification is one example where it will likely excel.
- **Check the model against the training set.** If it does poorly with the training set then it will likely have poor performance with unseen data. In general, you should expect the model to performance against the training to exceed the performance against unseen data.
- **The algorithm needs to be tested with data it has never seen**. Testing against the training set, while a quick elimination test, will likely lead to overconfidence.
- **Reserve some of your data for testing.**  Weka provides a way to do this. The best case scenario would be to build the model on all cases except one (Leave On Out Approach) then see how the model performs on the average with these.

But this assumes the data at hand are not in some way biased.

A second pitfall is to let the test results bias the way you build the model.For example, trying different models parameters until you get an acceptable test response.  With J48 it's not easy to allow this bias to creep in but if it did then you have just used your test set as an auxiliary training set.

- **Continue collecting more data; testing as long as possible.** Even after all of the above, you still won't know how useful the algorithm is  unless you can observe its performance against future cases. When what appears to be a good model starts behaving poorly then it's time to go back to the drawing board.

Surprisingly, there are a large number of fields (mostly in the soft sciences) which fail to see the need to verify the model with future data. But this is a matter better discussed elsewhere.

This may not be the answer you are looking for but it is the way things are.

In summary,

1. The training data set should cover the 'significant' variable configurations
2. You should verify the model against unseen data

Identifying (1) and doing (2) are the tricky bits. There is no cut-and-dried recipe to follow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. First I should've said that indeed I have modified the data set that I linked in my first post. I removed all the betting odds columns. The reason why I think my data set is wrongly structured is because looking at the decision tree I can see that the most important attributes considered by the algorithm are team 1 goals scored and team 2 goals scored. When making results prediction, those stats are not available so they should be eliminated. I will however try to concatenate multiple data sets and run the test again to see if anything changes.

Comment: Secondly, how does one find the proper algorithm? This requires a huge amount of time spent on trying every different algorithm out there and even more time spent on checking real predictions and see if they work and what's the success rate. That is absolutely insane

Comment: I've edited the answer to address the "how to get the right algorithm" part. Unfortunately, there is no one-size-fits-all answer.  Note to self: don't use numbered list items. Inserting new items between two of them requires a lot of work. Took me many edits to come to this conclusion.

Comment: As for which variables are most important, try using what J48 picks as the most important three variable as the only predictors (assuming the outcome the identification of the superior team in a match). It may surprise you, but you will likely never exceed this performance except against specific data sets. The J48 is incapable of identifying models such as (scoring record OR they wear yellow shirts) if the color of the shirt is a viable predictor but independent of the scoring record.